# How to connect to AutoSys via Azure data factory

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I need to trigger autosys job from Azure data factory.

I could not find any post on this.

could you please share some document, Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use the "Web activity" in Azure data factory to call an Autosys job using the Autosys JIL command language. Here are the general steps to follow:

- Create a JIL command to trigger the Autosys job like:

  update_job: my_job
  command: run_job.sh
  machine: my_server owner:
  my_user
- Create a Web activity in Azure Data Factory to call the Autosys job.
  In the Web activity, set the following parameters:

  URL: The URL to the Autosys server where the job is defined.
  Method: The HTTP method to use for the request (usually POST).
  Body: The JIL command to trigger the job.
- Add any required headers to the Web
  activity, such as authentication credentials or content type.
- Run the ADF pipeline containing the Web activity to trigger the
  Autosys job.

Comment: Thanks for your input
I connect to Autosys with this Address:-
https://fgrtht.grupp.de:1452/abb/ui/Launcher.html
what should I give in URL while creating web activity in ADF